# Understanding of sign representation

Tags: representation-theory

I have started to study representations theory. One of the trivial examples of representations is *sign representation* which is defined as the one that translates $\sigma \in S_n$ to sign$(\sigma)$. But images should lie in a $GL(V)$. What is V here and how the function looks like? E.g., given any permutation and $V$, what do we get?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group).: "For $S_n,n ≥ 2$, there is another irreducible representation of degree $1$, called the *sign representation* or alternating character, which takes a permutation to the one by one matrix with entry $±1$ based on the sign of the permutation." So $V$ is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Is it correct to think that having, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ we get a function that changes sign to +1 or -1 according to the sign of permutation?

Comment: We get a homomorphism $sign: S_n\rightarrow GL(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$, sending $\sigma$ to $sign(\sigma)$.

Comment: The sign representation is **not** trivial. The trivial representation takes all elements to the identity element.